# Free online resources for OOP class design?

Tags: oop

I love having a book in front of me, but right now I can't afford to buy anymore books and all my libraries suck, so I'm wondering what free sites/resources exist where I can learn about best practices for designing classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **Martin Fowler'**s [collection of enterprise patterns](http://martinfowler.com/articles/enterprisePatterns.html) is very good...

I not only has his but has Gang of Four, java, Microsoft, and many others...

Another good one is [Refactoring to Patterns Catalog](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/catalog.html), will help you refactor existing code to a pattern...

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP the [OOP manual pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) are invaluable.  For the more cerebral resources, how about [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?

A quick [google](http://www.google.com/) search finds: http://www.oodesign.com/ which seems to provide an extensive collection of design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Worth a look: the articles published by the people at Object Mentor: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html